# host(1) command only uses first nameserver?

Tags: linux, dns, dhcp, hosts

According to the man page, `host` ought to query "the server or servers listed in `/etc/resolv.conf`," but it only uses the first entry in that file:

```
thefourthtower:$cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 192.168.1.254
domain gateway.2wire.net
search gateway.2wire.net
thefourthtower:$host thefourthtower
Host thefourthtower not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
thefourthtower:$host thefourthtower 192.186.1.254
thefourthtower.gateway.2wire.net has address 192.168.1.74
```

The `2wire` bit comes from a 2Wire modem/router.  AT&T (or 2Wire?) have equipped the thing with very poor firmware and its DNS server (cache) is generally slower than Google Public DNS, a problem compounded by AT&T's own flaky DNS servers (no option for alternate servers).

Can I get `host` or `nslookup` to use further `/etc/resolv.conf` entries (and avoid specifying servers manually)?

Or is the only solution to manually map hosts in `/etc/hosts`, given the desired ordering of the `resolv.conf` entries?

**UPDATE**

Nothing in the above implies that I think Google's nameserver should know about my local hosts.

I am asking: can one use a certain nameserver for local names only (since a name like 'thefourthtower' must be local)?

It looks like the answer is **NO**, and I must run a nameserver on my machine, because the extant local nameserver is so poor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `host` command uses the resolver library, and that library uses the nameserver entries in /etc/resolv.conf in order, but only on failure. The purpose of multiple entries is for redundancy, in case the primary server fails for some reason. But it the primary server provides a response, whether positive or negative (e.g. NXDOMAIN), then the other nameserver entries are not used. You can have up to three, for triple redundancy.

External name server like Googles will not know about your local host names. You should put those in your /etc/hosts file, or run a local name server. Running a local name server has the advantage of caching DNS lookups, making future or repeat lookups much faster.

I use [dnsmasq](http://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) as a local DNS and cache. It really helps a lot.  Just set your `/etc/resolv.conf` to use `127.0.0.1` first (or only) nameserver, and configure dnsmasq to user your ISP upstream servers. Even if your ISP is slow, your local cache will compensate most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first two nameserver entries from `/etc/resolv.conf` if they do not know about hosts on your LAN or about the domain used locally.

The NXDOMAIN response might be because `gateway.2wire.net` isn't a registered domain name that can be used on the internet.

```
$ dig gateway.2wire.net any

; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-4.P1.el5_5.3 <<>> gateway.2wire.net any
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 7984
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gateway.2wire.net.             IN      ANY

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
2wire.net.              1200    IN      SOA     ns1.2wire.com. hostmaster.2wire.com. 2007041700 3600 600 604800 1200

;; Query time: 209 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.9#53(10.0.0.9)
;; WHEN: Tue Aug 30 13:29:23 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 95
```

Note that the authoritative nameservers for `2wire.net` say there is no such domain as `gateway.2wire.net`. I guess it is a convenience used by 2wire products at the LAN level only.

8.8.8.8 is a Google nameserver and should not be expected to know about hosts on your private LAN and the  somewhat strange configuration choices made by your 2wire router.

The name of the computer thefourthtower should appear in it's own `/etc/hosts` table (which you should arrange to be consulted before DNS) and really ought to be known to the DNS nameserver on your LAN (i.e. your 2wire router).

Does your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` contain `hosts: files dns` ?

Comment: I don't believe `nsswitch.conf` is respected by `host` since the entry in `/etc/hosts` exists.

Comment: @reve: true "host is a simple utility for performing DNS lookups" but I expect you are only using `host` to diagnose a name-resolution problem with an application. Applications that use `gethostbyname()` will be affected by `nsswitch.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to query *all* name servers in your /etc/resolv.conf:

```
grep '^nameserver' /etc/resolv.conf | cut -c 12- | xargs -i host [HOSTNAME] {}
```

Or, if you prefer `dig(1)`:

```
grep '^nameserver' /etc/resolv.conf | cut -c 12- | xargs -i dig @{} [HOSTNAME]
```